DownloadManager requests delayed
I installed a self-written app on my old Galaxy S9 phone with Android 10 (Q) that worked perfectly for years. For a few months now, however, it sometimes takes up to an hour (!) for my app to start downloading a pdf from the internet. Sometimes I also get an error message such as “Unable to start Receiver my.app.ReceiverDownladBroadcast. Android.content.Context.getPackagename() has a null object reference”. The DownloadManager throws the warning “Path appears to be invalid: /storage/emulated/0/Download/dl.pdf” despite write permission.
I found this problem several times on StackOverflow:
DownloadManager requests delayed on Android Pie, DownloadManager haves a huge delay in starting download, etc., but all suggested solutions (delete cache and storage from Download Manager, etc.) did not help. By the way, when I reboot my phone, the pending pdf is usually actually downloaded in the first few seconds after the reboot, but this approach is not acceptable as a solution. Has anyone found a solution to my problem in the past?
Here is my code:
...
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("https://.../dl.pdf");
...

webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
  @Override public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String 
    contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "dl.pdf");
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) ActivityMain.this.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
  }
});

